# Location authorization error even though I've asked for authorization in iOS 8 using swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, cllocationmanager

I have an app using the location services. If the app first starts, it ask the user for permission.
For some reason, if I tap on "Allow" I'll get this message:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization.
```

I know what this means, but I've set breakpoints all over my code and I am SURE that nothing tries to read the user location before it is allowed to do so.

Anyway, I seem to be missing something.

1) Is there a "common mistake" which one could do, something within the storyboard or so?
2) Will Apple reject an app that has such an error?

Thing is that the app works perfectly well, The only thing is that I see this message within the console. I don't know whether Apple will see this message too and if this would be a reason to reject an app..

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) { // iOS8+
    // Sending a message to avoid compile time error
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)
                                               to:self.locationManager
                                             from:self
                                         forEvent:nil];
} else {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

}

I think you may need to include something like this for the requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Comment: I did that. still I get these problems

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are using CLLocationManager. So did you make a **strong** reference to your *locationManager* object?

It seems to be a case when you requested location in local scope (variable) inside a function. Then trying to use MapKit, but locationManager object is already deallocated.

To solve that case, you should declare...

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

... as an instance variable, then request authorization, and then using location services.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I have asked for authorization to use location services if the app is in use and I have determined the authorization like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.restricted
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.denied
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.notDeterminded
                break
            default:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.allowed
                break
            }
    }
```

This seems to be wrong, the error is gone if I explicitly check for CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.restricted
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.denied
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.notDeterminded
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.allowed
            default:
                locationStatus = GpsStatus.notDeterminded
                break
            }
    }
```

EDIT:

Seems like it's also a problem to add a TrackingLocationButton before I have the permission to use location services.

So do this

```
     var userTrackingButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: self.mapView);
        self.toolBar.items?.insert(userTrackingButton, atIndex: 0)
```

only if you have the permission

Answer (score -1):

For iOS 8 you need to define the "Privacy - Location Usage Description" in the Info.plist.

Eg. **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** = "Use your location to show near by stores".

or

**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** = "Use your location to show near by stores".

This key specifies the reason for accessing the user’s location information.